# getActivity() inside viewholder

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have created a Recyclerview, with itemobjects, Adapter, viewholder and activity.

The Recyclerview works fine.

My problem is when an item is clicked from Recyclerview, I want to direct the user to TicketDetails activity.

I have the code to get the clicked item and its position in the view holder, but when I try to create a new intent to new activity like this  inside view holder

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TicketDetails.class));
```

I am unable to resolve getActivity()

**ViewHolder**

```
public class TicketsRecyclerViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public ImageView priority;
    public TextView sts_open;
    public TextView sts_overdue;
    public TextView tkt_from;
    public TextView tkt_subject;
    public TextView tkt_assignedto;
    public TextView tkt_created_date;
    public TextView txt_ticket_id;

    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();

    public TicketsRecyclerViewHolders(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        priority = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priority_status_icon);
        sts_open= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_opn_status);
        sts_overdue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_overdue);
        tkt_from = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_from);
        tkt_subject = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_subject);
        tkt_assignedto = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_Assignedto);
        tkt_created_date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_Created_date);
        txt_ticket_id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_Tk_TicketID);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        String ticket_id = txt_ticket_id.getText().toString();
        Log.d("ZD-clicked : ", "Position => "+String.valueOf(position)+", Ticket Id => "+ticket_id);

        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TicketDetails.class));

//        if (selectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
//            selectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition());
//            view.setSelected(false);
//        }
//        else {
//            selectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
//            view.setSelected(true);
//        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class TicketsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TicketsRecyclerViewHolders>{

    public List<TicketsItemObject> TicketsItemList;
    private Context context;


    public TicketsRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<TicketsItemObject> itemList) {
        this.TicketsItemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public TicketsRecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_tickets_row, null);
        TicketsRecyclerViewHolders rcv = new TicketsRecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TicketsRecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {

            holder.priority.setImageResource(TicketsItemList.get(position).getStatus_priority());
            holder.sts_open.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getStatus_open());
            holder.sts_overdue.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getStatus_overdue());
            holder.tkt_from.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getTicket_from());
            holder.tkt_subject.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getTicket_subject());
            holder.tkt_assignedto.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getTicket_assignedto());
            holder.tkt_created_date.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getTicket_created_date());
            holder.txt_ticket_id.setText(TicketsItemList.get(position).getTicket_id());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.TicketsItemList.size();
    }
}
```

**Item Object**

```
public class TicketsItemObject {
    private int status_priority;
    private String status_open;
    private String status_overdue;
    private String ticket_from;
    private String ticket_subject;
    private String ticket_assignedto;
    private String ticket_created_date;
    private String ticket_id;

    public TicketsItemObject(int status_priority, String status_open, String status_overdue, String ticket_from, String ticket_subject, String ticket_assignedto, String ticket_created_date, String ticket_id) {
        this.status_priority = status_priority;
        this.status_open = status_open;
        this.status_overdue = status_overdue;
        this.ticket_from = ticket_from;
        this.ticket_subject = ticket_subject;
        this.ticket_assignedto = ticket_assignedto;
        this.ticket_created_date = ticket_created_date;
        this.ticket_id =ticket_id;
    }

    public int getStatus_priority() {
        return status_priority;
    }

    public String getStatus_open() {
        return status_open;
    }

    public String getStatus_overdue() {
        return status_overdue;
    }

    public String getTicket_from() {
        return ticket_from;
    }

    public String getTicket_subject() {
        return ticket_subject;
    }

    public String getTicket_assignedto() {
        return ticket_assignedto;
    }

    public String getTicket_created_date(){return ticket_created_date;}

    public String getTicket_id(){return ticket_id;}

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ListView drawerList;
    private navigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment;

    private CompanyProfileAdapter mAdapter;
    ApplicationEnvironmentURL applicationEnvironment;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Context context;
    String BASEURL;
    String FilteredData;
    String allAgents;
    List<TicketsItemObject> items = new ArrayList<TicketsItemObject>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
    private TicketsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Dashboard");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

        applicationEnvironment = new ApplicationEnvironmentURL(this.context);
        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar_dashboard);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        drawerFragment = (navigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);



        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("zupportdesk", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String islogged = prefs.getString("islogged", "Not defined");
        String userid = prefs.getString("userid", "Not defined");
        String profileToken = prefs.getString("profileToken", "Not defined");
        String companyId = prefs.getString("companyId", "Not defined");
        String companyName = prefs.getString("companyName", "Not defined");
        String ProfileId = prefs.getString("ProfileId", "Not defined");

        Log.d("islogged     : ", islogged);
        Log.d("userid       : ", userid);
        Log.d("profileToken : ", profileToken);
        Log.d("companyId    : ", companyId);
        Log.d("companyName  : ", companyName);
        Log.d("ProfileId    : ", ProfileId);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_tickets);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Dashboard.this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        getTickets(ProfileId, companyId, profileToken);

        View newTicket = findViewById(R.id.newtic);
        newTicket.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);




    }

    /* Multiple Button on click event handle */
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.newtic:
                    // Create a login URl, before starting anything

                    if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                        Intent intentTicket = new Intent(Dashboard.this, NewTicket.class);
                        startActivity(intentTicket);
                    } else {showErrorMessage("Please check your internet connection.", "No Connectivity!"); }
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


    private void getTickets(String profileId, String companyId, String profileToken){
        if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
            try {
                setFilteredDataURL(companyId);
                FilteredData = new getFilteredData().execute(profileToken).get();


                Log.d("Full Filtered Data", FilteredData);
                setTicketsURL(profileId, companyId);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new getNewTickets().execute(profileToken);
        }else{ showErrorMessage("Please check your internet connection.", "No Connectivity!"); }
    }
................
.............
..More...........
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getActivity()` only works in fragments. A view will have activity Context. So get Context from the view.

Change

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), TicketDetails.class));
```

to

```
Context context = view.getContext();
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, TicketDetails.class));
```

Comment: Hy Tnx. But now am unable to resolve `startActivity`. i cleaned the project and rebut the project `Error:(62, 9) error: cannot find symbol method startActivity(Intent)`

Comment: Updated the answer, use context to start Activity.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
holder.itemView.context as Activity
```

Comment: Inside `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: You have to clearly mention those information in the answer. Otherwise answer is not a complete one

Comment: Inside `override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int)` of Adapter you can get activity by `holder.itemView.context as Activity`.
You can turn on dialog or anything need activity inside a holder.

Answer (score 1):

## Interface approach

You can also solve this problem using interface

**1) Create an interface**

```
public interface ItemclickListerner{

   public void startActivity(int index);

}
```

**2) Implement the interface in the Activity**

```
public class YourActivity extends AppcompatActivity implements ItemclickListerner{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
 
    .......

    @override
    public void startActivity(int index)
    {
       Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)
       startActivity(i);
    }
 
}
```

**3) Use the ItemclickListerner in the holder**

```
public class TicketsRecyclerViewHolders extends ....  {

   private ItemclickListerner listener;

   // Typecast the listener 
   public TicketsRecyclerViewHolders(Context context)
   {
      listener = (ItemclickListerner)context;
   }

   // Call the listener method

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(TicketsRecyclerViewHolders holder, int position{
       listener.startActivity(position)
   }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface to pass the itemclick from Adapter to your activity or fragment. Inside the callback you can call the Intent.

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) for more info. See @Jacob Tabaks answer.

EDIT:

See @AkshayBhat's answer for an alternative method.

Comment: I agree, but when you can get context from the view, why extra interface and code.

Comment: Agreed. Never used that method before. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have `context` in your constructor.So you can use context to go to an `Activity` from adapter.

```
Intent goTicket = new Intent(context, MyDetailActivity.class);
 goTicket.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass `fragment` to the Adaptar constructor.
2. Check if `fragment` is currently added to its activity and then launch particular activity:

   `if (fragment.isAdded())`

   ```
    fragment.startActivity(intent)
   ```